# Why filterAcceptsRow when inheriting from QSortFilterProxyModel is not invoked?

Tags: c++, windows, qt, qsortfilterproxymodel

There is a class named customSortFilterProxyModel inheriting from QSortFilterProxyModel. And one protected function filterAcceptsRow is override.
But, filterAcceptsRow is not called at all. what is the promblem?
thanks.
customSortFilterProxyModel.h

```
class customSortFilterProxyModel: public QSortFilterProxyModel
        {
           Q_OBJECT

        public:
            customSortFilterProxyModel(QObject *parent);
            ~customSortFilterProxyModel();

        protected:
           virtual bool filterAcceptsRow(int source_row, const QModelIndex &source_parent) const override;   
        };

//customSortFilterProxyModel.cpp
customSortFilterProxyModel::customSortFilterProxyModel(QObject *parent)
: QSortFilterProxyModel(parent)
{
}
customSortFilterProxyModel::~customSortFilterProxyModel()
{

}
bool customSortFilterProxyModel::filterAcceptsRow(int source_row, const QModelIndex &source_parent) const
{
   return true;
}
```

Test code using this proxy model

```
    QStringListModel *newModel = new QStringListModel;
    QStringList strList;
    strList << "1" << "2" << "3" << "4";
newModel->setStringList(strList);
    customSortFilterProxyModel   *m_customSortFilterProxyModel = new customSortFilterProxyModel(this);
       m_customSortFilterProxyModel->setSourceModel(newModel);
```

Answer (score 0):

call this function for sort column

m_customSortFilterProxyModel->sort(0);

Answer (score 0):

I force my customSortFilterProxyModel to reload the source model by
setSourceModel. It works. But I am not sure is it the right solution or not?